# Replacement for Almond Milk

Tags: baking, substitutions, milk, almond-milk

I have a muffin recipe for Almond milk but I'd like to replace it since Almond Milk is only good for 7-10 days, I can't find small enough containers, and no one in my household will drink it.  Outside of replacing it with other forms of milk, what are some substitutes for Almond Milk?

Comment: 7-10 days? The almond milk I get lasts weeks.

Comment: Yeah I used the Almond Breeze and it says "Please use within 7 - 10 days."  What brand are you using?

Comment: I use Alpro, a UK brand @BrianMains.

Comment: @GdD I would be very surprised if it really lasts that long. Note that the date printed on the package is only valid for a sealed package, and that it won't necessary have visible signs of spoilage at the time it has dangerous levels of bacteria.

Comment: I've been using the same brand for years @rumtscho, it lasts significantly longer than 7-10 days, and I am careful.

Comment: Why specifically are you asking for a non-milk replacement?  Are you afraid your muffins will only be good for the 7-10 days that the package says the milk is good for?  I'm confused by "Outside of replacing it with other forms of milk"?

Comment: You may be able to find smaller containers of almond (or other non-dairy) milk in a different section of the grocery store. The refrigerated half-gallon containers are too large for my family as well, but we can get through the shelf stable size -- 1 quart -- in a week.

Answer (score 2):

To make your life easier, I'd look for another muffin recipe that does not use almond milk.

You should be able to substitute with rice milk, soy milk.. or even regular milk (cow, sheep ...) or other non animal milk.

For example, this site tested muffins with different kind of milks.

https://teaspoonofspice.com/almond-milk-muffins/

Answer (score 1):

Just use water instead, or regular cow milk.

Comment: Will water affect the flavor profile?

Comment: Almond milk is pretty bland.

Answer (score 1):

My wife is lactose intolerant and doesn't particularly care for almond milk. I have successfully used Cashew Milk in everything from cereal to most baking recipes (where almond milk will work)